# Retrieve the catalog data from wooCommerce site

Tags: woocommerce

I have a requirement where I want to retrieve all the products present in the wooCommerce site and get all the attributes associated with it such as product id,Product Image Url,Product Name,price, color,instock or not etc.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can retrieve all products in your catalog:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'     => -1,
    'orderby'         => 'title',
    'order'           => 'ASC',
    'post_type'       => 'product',
    'post_status'     => 'publish'
);

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $products->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
        $products->the_post();
        $_product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
    }
}
```

Depending on what information you want, you may need to call Woocommerce functions to get it.